# Controller issue : losing access

Tags: websphere-liberty

Using V8.5.5.9 with Java 7 on two different machines running Windows. I have been through all the process for "RXA Setup for Collective Operations" :UAC, Sharing Registry .... I have googled it but i am struggling with this problem :

It looks like the connection is working and after 40s ... Boom it is losing it. Any idea ?

**Machine 1: Main** ( 192.168.0.39 )

***Server.xml***

> < collectiveController replicaPort="10010"
>                            replicaSet="cogito1:10010"
>                            isInitialReplicaSet="false" host="main" 
>   replicaHost="main"/>

***Log***

[16-06-07 12:36:06:301 EDT] 00000011 com.ibm.ws.frappe.paxos.impl.CommandsExecutor:10010          I CWWKX6013I: The collective controller state is No Paxos Instance, last proposed command is -1, the last accepted command is -1, the last executed command is 0 and the log is 274.

[16-06-07 12:36:06:617 EDT] 00000029 .utils.service.multiplexed.impl.UniverseAndReplicaData:10010 I CWWKX6009I: The collective controller successfully connected to replica 192.168.0.39:10010. Current active replica set is []. The configured replica set is [192.168.0.162:10010]. The connected standby replicas are [192.168.0.39:10010].

[16-06-07 12:36:06:835 EDT] 00000029 .utils.service.multiplexed.impl.UniverseAndReplicaData:10010 I CWWKX6009I: The collective controller successfully connected to replica 192.168.0.162:10010. Current active replica set is [192.168.0.162:10010]. The configured replica set is [192.168.0.162:10010]. The connected standby replicas are [192.168.0.39:10010].

[16-06-07 12:36:46:355 EDT] 00000025 e.serviceregistry.backend.RegistryReplicationService:default E CWWKX6008E: The collective controller is unavailable, probably due to a loss of majority of the replica set, or a comm

**Machine 2: Cogito1** ( 192.168.0.162 )

***Server.xml***

> < collectiveController replicaPort="10010" replicaSet="cogito1:10010" 
>    isInitialReplicaSet="true" />

***Log***

[16-06-07 12:36:06:301 EDT] 00000011 com.ibm.ws.frappe.paxos.impl.CommandsExecutor:10010          I CWWKX6013I: The collective controller state is No Paxos Instance, last proposed command is -1, the last accepted command is -1, the last executed command is 0 and the log is 274.

[16-06-07 12:36:06:617 EDT] 00000029 .utils.service.multiplexed.impl.UniverseAndReplicaData:10010 I CWWKX6009I: The collective controller successfully connected to replica 192.168.0.39:10010. Current active replica set is []. The configured replica set is [192.168.0.162:10010]. The connected standby replicas are [192.168.0.39:10010].

[16-06-07 12:36:06:835 EDT] 00000029 .utils.service.multiplexed.impl.UniverseAndReplicaData:10010 I CWWKX6009I: The collective controller successfully connected to replica 192.168.0.162:10010. Current active replica set is [192.168.0.162:10010]. The configured replica set is [192.168.0.162:10010]. The connected standby replicas are [192.168.0.39:10010].

[16-06-07 12:36:46:355 EDT] 00000025 e.serviceregistry.backend.RegistryReplicationService:default E CWWKX6008E: The collective controller is unavailable, probably due to a loss of majority of the replica set, or a comm

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're trying to set up two replica controllers, one on host main and the other on host cogito1.  Based on that assumption, you need to ensure unique replicaPorts for each controller.  In other words, your configuration for main should not be replicaPort="10010", but instead another free port, like replicaPort="10011".

Also, note that for High Availability, you need a **minimum** of 3 replica controllers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have not completed the addReplica step for 192.168.0.39.  It seems to always be in the standby set, which would be true if it has not been added via this command.  For example you can see the command in the current Beta documentation here:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tagt_wlp_configure_replicas.html

With a replica set of two replicas and one not having been added, this will result in an inoperable set. One replica is not a majority of the 2 total replicas, thus it cannot reach an operable state.